# ignoring & in DOM XML parser

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, saxparser

I am trying to parse an XML file using SAX parser.But when it finds an `&` it gives me an error "The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.".How can i make the parser to ignore '&' while parsing or if possible to convert it into & from the DTD itself

Comment: Those textual ampersands should be written as `&amp;` to be correct XML. `string = string.replace("&", "&amp;");`

Comment: Actually, you are trying to parse a non-XML file. You can't make an XML parser parse non-XML. You have to change the input to make it well-formed XML, preferably by fixing the code that generated it in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Your input is not valid XML, since it seems to contain `&` characters which are not followed by an entity name or character reference.

The cleanest way to solve this is to make sure that the input is valid XML before you parse it, i.e. replace the offending `&` characters with `&amp;`.

I don't think you can convince any decent XML parser to silently ignore XML syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

1. Find the person/entity responsible for producing the invalid XML input
2. Make sure that person/entity never again in his/her/its life will ever be *capable* of producing invalid XML again
3. Repeat for any new offender

> Use of unnecessary violence in the apprehension of the XML villains HAS been approved

Or, you can just resign and use [TagSoup](http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/tagsoup/) or something similar.